# &nbsp; in String.Format(...) for currency

Tags: asp.net-mvc, string, formatting, view, currency

I use `String.Format` to do currency formatting. It works great, but I want a non-breaking space (`&nbsp;`) between the currency symbol (R) and the value so it doesn't wrap in small spaces, making it harder to read.

```
<%=String.Format("{0:R #,###.00;(R #,###.00);R 0.00}", Model)%>
```

where `Model` is a `decimal`.

How do I add `&nbsp;` between `R` and `#,###.00` without confusing the `String.Format` method?

Comment: I used to have `R&nbsp;{0:#,###.00;(#,###.00);R 0.00}` but then negative numbers look like `R (1,234.56)` instead of `(R 1,234.56)`.

Comment: Do you what the _character_ or the character entity?

Comment: If I didn't want it to wrap, I'd simply remove the space and but the currency symbol against the amount. However, this is how I'd write a currency anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it be possible to wrap the result in an element with the css white-space property set?

```
<span style="white-space:nowrap;"><%=String.Format("{0:R #,###.00;(R #,###.00);R 0.00}", Model)%></span>
```

Comment: exactly what I was going to suggest (I wouldn't have used an inline style, but it's probably the best way to demonstrate it in this context)

Comment: I ended up doing this myself, but with a .nowrap class.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%=String.Format("{0:R&nbsp;#,###.00;(R&nbsp;#,###.00);R&nbsp;0.00}", Model)%>
```

No?